# Grid with json store sometimes don't show data

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, store, extjs4.1

I have a extjs 4 grid panel with remote stores.
On the renderer of column there is function, which change ID to NAME.
Mostly times it works fine, but sometimes (~40%) the grid shows with empty columns.
I've tried to debug - the store is defined, but its items are empty.
To my mind store not loaded yet, or already destroyed (if it is possible).

How to correctly show grid, with full data?

There is my simplified code:

### Loading needed components

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled:true
});

Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '/js/ux');

Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function () {
```

### Create models

```
    Ext.define('Expense', {
        extend:'Ext.data.Model',
        fields:[
            {name:'id', type:'number'},
            {name:'cost_id', type:'string'},
            {name:'comment', type:'string'}

        ]
    });

    Ext.define('Cost', {
        extend:'Ext.data.Model',
        fields:[
            {name:'id', type:'string'},
            {name:'name', type:'string'},
            {name:'displayname', type:'string'}
        ]
    });
```

### Create stores

```
    store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoDestroy:true,
        model:'Expense',
        autoLoad:true,
        autoSync:true,
        pageSize:30,
        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            url:'/expenses/gettable',
            reader:{
                type:'json',
                root:'data',
                record:'Expense'
            }, writer:{
                type:'json'
            },
            api:{
                create:'/expenses/create',
                update:'/expenses/update',
                destroy:'/expenses/delete'
            }
        }
    });

    costsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        autoDestroy:true,
        model:'Cost',
        autoLoad:true,
        autoSync:true,
        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            url:'/costs/gettable',
            reader:{
                type:'json',
                record:'Cost'
            }, writer:{
                type:'json',

                allowSingle:false
            },
            api:{
                create:'/costs/create',
                update:'/costs/update'
            }
        }
    });
```

### Configure grid panel

```
    grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store:store,
        autoSync:true,
        columns:[
            {
                id:'comment',
                header:'Задача',
                dataIndex:'comment',
                flex:5
            },
            {
                id:'cost',
                header:'Cost',
                dataIndex:'cost_id',
                flex:5,
                editor:{
                    xtype:'combobox',
                    store:costsStore,
                    valueField:'id',
                    displayField:'name',
                    name:'cost_id'
                },
                renderer:function (value, meta, record) {
                    if (value != '') {
                        ind = costsStore.find('id', value);
                        elem = costsStore.getAt(ind);
                        if (elem) {

                            return elem.data['name'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        renderTo:'editor-grid'
    });

});
```

I've tried to manually load stores on grid render event:

```
grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    listeners:{
        beforerender:function(){
            store.load();
            costsStore.load();
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

It is decrease empty table to ~10% cases, but not 0%...

The only way I've found is to set delay after loading all stores, and then show grid, something like this:

```
listeners:{
    'load':function(){
        window.setTimeout("getGrid()", 1000);
    }
}
```

Where getGrid() is the function with creating grid.panel.

What I have to do, to show grid only after all stores loaded, or show error if data can't load?

Comment: And one more working variant: 1. Place grid configuration to the function (getGrid()), then, load store with callback function, and show grid only after all callbacks were executed... But I don't know is it good variant, or I can make something better.

Answer (score 0):

As sra suggested - your problem seems to stem from using a store within a renderer, while you cannot be sure that store is loaded.

I have described what I think is the most elegant solution to this problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993003/extjs4-how-to-share-data-between-multiple-stores-or-models/11996148#11996148), with some code examples.