# ExtJS: Confused about the Model Package

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm confused about to how to properly use Models/Stores/Proxies/Readers in ExtJS 4. I've read the guides and looked at the examples, but still can't see the solution to my problem.

**Goal:** Say I am working with `car` objects (for which a model exists), which contain (among other things):

- Car identifiers (VIN#, Make, Model, Year, Color, ect)
- Ownership history
- Maintenance history
- Detailed list of car components (engine: {L-Twin cylinder, 2 valve per cylinder Desmodromic, air cooled}, front brake : {}, ...)

And assume I'm using the VIN# as a primairy key, and that I have a RESTfull API setup like

```
GET /car                 // gets list of cars
GET /car/123abc          // gets car with VIN# 123abc
```

Now, if I have a reference to a VIN# in a controller, what I want to do is launch a *complex dashboard* that may have components like:

- A grid for the car components
- A chart for maintenance costs vs time
- A custom panel for displaying the Make, Model, Year
- ect

**Problem:**
Say I have a `Car` model, and a `CarComponent` model, where my server is configured to send nested data (i.e. no API for dealing directly with `CarComponent`'s). Ideally... I just want to request the car data from the server with a simple `GET /car/<the vin #>` and use the returned data to populate all the components of the complex dashboard. So my attempt strategy is:

- Models: `Car`, `CarComponent`
- Stores: `Cars`
- Proxies: a single rest proxy attached to the `Car` model
- somehow use nested properties of a `Car` to fill the components (ex. the grid of components)

Or do I need separate stores for the components? Also, I can't tell how the Stores work; I **don't** want to load all cars from the server.. just the specified one. I'm just confused on how to string together the models/proxies/stores to accomplish what I need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation like this, where you have a separate grid for the cars and a separate grid for the components, the ideal setup would be to have API for dealing with CarComponent's as well. Since you have mentioned this is not the case, I would recommend to define two separate stores. They would issue same GET request for loading the data, but you will specify different [root readers](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-root). If your server returns data similar to:

```
{
    Car:
    {
        color:blue,
        CarComponent:
        {
            engine: {..}
        }
        ..
    }
}
```

then one store (let's call it CarStore) would have reader root `Car` and the other one (let's call it CarComponentStore) `Car.CarComponent`. Disadvantage of this approach is that you'll have to issue two requests each time, one for Car and other for CarComponent, even though the returned data will be the same. However, this can be avoided by using the concept of "master" and "slave" store, see this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993003/extjs4-how-to-share-data-between-multiple-stores-or-models) that explains it.

In the Car grid, you have to set a store to CarStore, in the CarComponent to CarComponentStore. By correctly defining reader roots, both grids will "automagically" be populated with the appropriate data from the response.

> I don't want to load all cars from the server..

Well, you don't have to unless you don't have a clue of VIN#. Most APis have a support for pagination, so you can fetch cars 10 by 10 for example, or you can include [remote filtering](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-remoteFilter) to filter the records on the server side. But the first prerequisite is to know which car you want to retrieve :-)

Comment: Good idea man thanks for responding. I went with what you said with 2 separate stores - but instead of doing 2 requests, I do 1 request for the car to load the carstore, then manually populate the componentstore

Comment: @Colin I have added how to use only one request to populate both stores, a concept that you already successfully applied :)