# Treepanel with nested data from JSON

Tags: json, sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs

I want to add nested data from JSON into a treepanel. My problem is that the tree is being listed for the number of JSON records (number of divisions, here 1 in the example) without any text. But when I select a child, it shows **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined**  error. This is what I have tried so far.

JSON file (schemesInfo.json).

```
{
"divisions":[
{"name": "division1","id": "div1","subdivisions":[
    {"name": "Sub1Div1","id": "div1sub1","schemes":[
        {"name": "Scheme1","id": "scheme1"},
        {"name": "Scheme2","id": "scheme2"}]},
    {"name": "Sub2Div1","id": "div1sub2","schemes":[
        {"name": "Scheme3","id": "scheme3"}]}

]}]
}
```

Model : (schemesmodel.js)

```
   Ext.define('GridApp.model.schemesmodel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['name','id'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'data/schemesInfo.json'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'divisions'
        }
    }
    });
```

Store : (schemesstore.js)

```
    Ext.define('GridApp.store.schemesstore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'GridApp.model.schemesmodel',
    autoLoad: true,

    listeners: {
        load:function(){
            console.log('Schemes Data store loaded');
        }
    },
    root: {
        text: "Divisions",
        expanded: true,
        id: 'NULL'
//      children: [
//                 {
//                     text:['name'],
////                       id: 'divsionnameid',
////                       leaf: true
//                 }]
    }
});
```

I am pretty new to Extjs 4. Let me know where I am going wrong. Any points regarding this will be very helpful.

Updated the question based on the discussion with @Izhaki.

Comment: Model doesn't have an `id` config, are you confusing it with `idProperty'?

Comment: Also, it appears from your code that neither `subdivisions` nor `schemes` should show up as children on the tree. Is that correct?

Comment: @Izhaki, Yes. Just saw that. I was confusing with idProperty. For your second, i want all the children to be displayed..

Comment: @Izhaki, and I don't know how the children can be displayed..

Comment: Well, TreePanel (and the corresponding TreeStore) deal with parent/child relationship of the same model. ie, all the nodes have to be based on the same model. Using hasMany is something rather different and won't help you in displaying your data hierarchy on the tree. As all you models have the same id/name fields. Why not just use single model?

Comment: @Izhaki, I just followed the example from http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader. Since, I thought that is the way to display parent-child data.. Can you post a small example using single model?? or some links with examples would also be fine..

Comment: The docs you are referring to show loading nested data into a nested model (with associations). It does not apply for Trees. See [my reply to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763648/) for tree related code.

Comment: In a json the root and all children nodes have to have the same name (the tree is read recursively internally). So `subdivisions` have to change to `divisions` (since your readers' root property is set to `divisions`).

Comment: accordingly, schemes has to change to `divisions` as well.

Comment: @Izhaki, I have updated my JSON.. i am now able to get all the children but without any text.. Just the folders alone are visible.. do i have to set any text property for the children?

Comment: Does your TreePanel has `displayField: 'name'` config?

Comment: @Izhaki, yeah.. just found out that.. thanks.. you really deserve some reps.. can you add whatever u suggested as an answer? I will accept it.. it will be helpful for others too.. And many thanks for your help again.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property that represents children in your JSON has to be consist and match the `root` property of your reader. As yours is `divisions` you JSON should be:

```
{
   "divisions":[
      {
         "name":"division1",
         "id":"div1",
         "divisions":[
            {
               "name":"Sub1Div1",
               "id":"div1sub1",
               "divisions":[
                  {
                     "name":"Scheme1",
                     "id":"scheme1"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"Scheme2",
                     "id":"scheme2"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "name":"Sub2Div1",
               "id":"div1sub2",
               "divisions":[
                  {
                     "name":"Scheme3",
                     "id":"scheme3"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Also, don't forget `displayField: 'name'` in your TreePanel configs.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But if suppose the JSON i received is just like the one I posted in the question.. In that case how can I form a tree panel out of it with parent child relationships? any suggestions for that??

Comment: I'm still looking into that, by the way.

Comment: Hi liaK, I've got an answer, but I think it's best if you post this question as a separate one, because I believe many people would refer to it in the future. I believe the title of the question should be "Loading TreeStore from JSON with varying children fields", and just give your json as an example. I'm working on a JsFiddle to show how it's done.

Comment: i have added a separate question for that.